# Analyzing Windows Store crash report

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-store-apps, crash-reports, windows-store

I’m trying to figure out the cause for a crash from the quality report given in Windows Store Dev Center. I opened the attached file in Visual Studio and got the following call stack, with this I have no clue. I’m looking for some help in analyzing it,
I guess I have all of the symbols downloaded it is of 1.09 GB. I'll send my crash dump to anyone who wishes to help.
Call Stack:

```
combase.dll!75682716()                Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for combase.dll]    
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5e3dd13b()             Unknown
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5e555442()              Unknown
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5ddaed49()             Unknown
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5ddabd77()             Unknown
user32.dll!771e77d8()    Unknown
user32.dll!771e78cb()    Unknown
user32.dll!771e787a()    Unknown
user32.dll!771e899d()    Unknown
combase.dll!755ca8b8()                Unknown
windows.ui.dll!5f5711dc()            Unknown
windows.ui.dll!5f571290()            Unknown
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5de92746()             Unknown
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5de92705()             Unknown
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5de926c9()              Unknown
Windows.UI.Xaml.dll!5de926a4()             Unknown
twinapi.dll!703cc9dd()   Unknown
twinapi.dll!703ccab2()    Unknown
twinapi.dll!703cc9f6()     Unknown
SHCore.dll!74995a10()   Unknown
kernel32.dll!7541850d() Unknown
ntdll.dll!77a3bf39()          Unknown
ntdll.dll!77a3bf0c()          Unknown
```

Thanks,
Siva

Comment: can you share the dmp?

Comment: Okay, so the first thing you need to do is load it up into the debugger. Then, move up the stack about one or two steps. Check the `Locals` tab and you should be able to find a variable which stores the `string` version of the `Message` from the exception, along with the exception type.

Comment: Hi @magicandre1981 can you share your mail id or ping me at sivatcs@live.com. So that I'll send you the dmp.

Comment: the dump is not really helpful. There is an *internal Exception*, but I can't get a useful stack from this triage dump. I need a full dump.

Comment: That's the dump I got from Win Store, How full dump will be?

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: Nope I have asked it to MS support engineer no hope yet!

Comment: @Sivakumarc send it to Andrew Richards and hope he can see anything useful from it. You can watch his video here for some details about analyzing the new store app crashes: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-64-Windows-81-Store-App-Crash-c000027b

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the dev center provided crash dumps include some crashes that are OS related and are nothing you can even do anything about.

Since this question was asked things have been improved greatly (see https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/2464852-vastly-improve-stack-trace-reporting) but there are still the possibilities of getting information about crashes that are outside your app. Hopefully this will be addressed in future too.